# JSP - Basic HTML Form 'GET' - How to get a response data back

Tags: html, jsp, forms

I need to be able to post data to an external site, and get a response back. When I say response, I mean the heading standard 200 code, but also system supplied data in the response back.

I have tried this with AJAX post, but my issue is cross site scripting, I have had too many problems with this.

is there a way to do a standard form post in my JSP, to an external URL - but how do I get the response values back out of this in my calling JSP.

I am running on Spring inside JBOSS.

My form is simple:

```
<form name="input" action="http://somesite.com/getResponse" method="get">
  forename: <input type="text" name="forename" />
  surname: <input type="text" name="surname" />
  age: <input type="text" name="age" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Send the request from your server instead of sending it from the browser.

Comment: hi @JBNizet, the issue is, there is a wish to send from the broswer. I have the ability to send from my servlet, but there is an issue with performance for this. The preference is to send from the broswer. Are you aware of any way I can do this to get a response?